# OSX 10.9.1: "Tomcat started." localhost:8080 says "no data received"

Tags: java, macos, tomcat

I've spent hours trying to get Tomcat installed and the server running, and still nothing.

```
❯ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents

❯ bash startup.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /Library/Tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /Library/Tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /Library/Tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Using CLASSPATH:       /Library/Tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/Library/Tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Using CATALINA_PID:    /Library/Tomcat/tomcat.pid
Existing PID file found during start.
Removing/clearing stale PID file.

Tomcat started.

/Library/Tomcat/bin
❯
```

localhost:8080 still doesn't load.

[image: Chrome: "no data received"]

I've checked, and no other processes are using that port.
I've also added a dummy user. Still, nothing.

```
<role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="role1"/>
  <role rolename="manager"/>
  <role rolename="admin"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,admin,manager"/>
  <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
  <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
```

Configuration tests:

```
❯ ./catalina.sh configtest
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /Library/Tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /Library/Tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /Library/Tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Using CLASSPATH:       /Library/Tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/Library/Tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Using CATALINA_PID:    /Library/Tomcat/tomcat.pid
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/catalina/startup/Bootstrap : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Configuration error detected!

❯ which java
/usr/bin/java

❯ java -version
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)
```

Yet, for some reason, I have 1.7 showing in my System Preferences.

[image: Java OSX System Prefs]

I even tried Tomcat Controller, but it says something isn't configured properly also.
It'd be really helpful if these errors told me exactly what the problem was.

[image: Tomcat Controller]

**Feel free to move this to ServerFault**

Answer (score 2):

You have two JVMs installed. Not the `JRE_HOME` line in the output from startup and compare it with the `JAVA_HOME` path above it.

You'll need to update the JRE_HOME environment variable and the java symlink in /usr/bin to point to the java 7 installation.

Comment: `❯ cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/
cd: no such file or directory: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/
~
❯ cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
❯ ls

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
❯ 
`

Appears to be nothing in the 1.7 JDK. How is that possible?

Comment: Apple decide to backtrack and remove support for JDK 7 from their official releases.

Comment: I had Tomcat 7 running at one point, but now it isn't. What should my environment variables look like in a standard install?